# How much can I make with an Nvidia 1080ti?

Tags: hardware

Within an order of magnitude error, how many EUR can I make by running said video card 24/7 for a month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check something like Nicehash profitability calculator to have an approximation: https://www.nicehash.com/profitability-calculator

Comment: The result was ~100EUR per month per GPU.

Comment: It seems too much; a 2060S returns around 2.4€ /day , not considering electricity cost